# How to format data with LINQ to Entities in the following format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

Using LINQ can I get the data from the table into the format shown directly below?  Can LINQ perform this type of formating or should I loop through the results to format?

**Format I'm trying to get data into:**

```
dau      gmu           population     year    
------   ----------    ----------    -------
1        2, 201        1680          2010
2        3, 4, 5, 14   14570         2010
```

**DATA IN TABLE:**

```
 id          dau         gmu         population         year species
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------- ---- -------
1           1           2           1680                2010 E
2           1           201         1680                2010 E
3           2           3           14570               2010 E
4           2           4           14570               2010 E
5           2           5           14570               2010 E
6           2           14          14570               2010 E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual formatting will be up to you, but assuming that you have a collection of these items called `list`, you can do this:

```
var result = from x in list
             group x by new {x.dau, x.population, x.year} into p
             select new 
{
    dau = p.Key.dau,
    population = p.Key.population,
    year = p.Key.year,
    gmu = p.Select (x => x.gmu)

};
```

You may have to pull this into an in-memory list to do this, if you're actually dealing with L2E.

*EDIT:  Just tried it with L2E and it seems to work fine as written.  Instead of `list` in your query, it will be something more like `context.TableName`.*

Here's the full code.  The output is very sloppy, but it's late, and I don't think the OP was worrying about the formatting so much:

```
        var result = from x in list.Stacko1
                     group x by new { x.dau, x.population, x.year } into p
                     select new
                     {
                         dau = p.Key.dau,
                         population = p.Key.population,
                         year = p.Key.year,
                         gmu = p.Select(x => x.gmu)

                     };

        result.ToList().ForEach(item=>
                                    {
                                        System.Console.Write("{0}\t\t", item.dau);

                                        item.gmu.ToList().ForEach(gmuElement=>
                                                                      {
                                                                          System.Console.Write("{0},", gmuElement);
                                                                      });


                                        System.Console.Write("\t\t");
                                        System.Console.Write("{0}\t\t", item.population);
                                        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.year);
                                    });

        System.Console.ReadKey();
```